# Using landing page to receive data from a callback

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, landing-page, httppost, callback

I am using MC Event notification Service and I created a callback (using a 3rd party site) to receive data posted back from Marketing Cloud.

I want to see if I can utilize a landing page to receive data (basically use the LP as a public site to receive event notifications from MC). Once I receive the data I want to parse/write the data to a DE.

Did anyone try this. Can a landing page receive data. Appreciate any examples.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Tried this : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209111/ssjs-landing-page-access-post-json-request-payload... seems to be working ok but some people are mentioning Platform.Request.GetPostData(0) may not be reliable... not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Code Resource (for example JSON one) instead of Cloud Page.  It's faster and doesn't cost you Super Messages.

You can capture the POST data with SSJS and output it to Data Extension (or leverage any other possible logic with SSJS functions).

One thing I would strongly recommend would be to add some kind of security, for example by passing a secret key in the post to limit the risk of malicious/spammy posts targeting this public receiver.